# Not able to place the order If it is configurable product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, configurable-product, checkout-page, place-order

Not able to order configurable product If I click on Proceed to checkout it will take us to payment page then if we click on Place order it'll get redirected to "http://fourkart.co.in/test3/checkout/cart/" page

Comment: Check your logs for error.
which payment method you are using ?

Comment: We are still in development mode if we select cash delivery also getting the same issue. Tell me which log I need to check.

Comment: Check exception.log in var folder

Comment: This is the exception showing in log                                                           [2019-03-22 12:03:44] main.CRITICAL: Could not connect to host {"exception":"[object] (SoapFault(code: 0): Could not connect to host at /home/pinnacle/fourkart.co.in/test3/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php:511)"} []

Comment: You log shows, the checkout page is trying to get the shipping cost from fedex carrier. Can you check whether fedex is enabled in backend if so is this configured with proper fedex account credentials?

Comment: Earlier it was enabled and I disabled it after this also it's not working and I can place sample product It'd working fine